# Read Bytes data from fetch response

Tags: arrays, react-native, kotlin

I want to convert an Android-Kotlin project to React Native, and I have a problem:

The Kotlin project handle data fetch from api like that:

```
import java.net.URL
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.ByteOrder

fun getData() {

    val bytes = try {
        URL(address).readBytes()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return emptySet()
    }

    val arrayBuffer = ByteBuffer
        .wrap(bytes)
        .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
    }

    return arrayBuffer
}


fun URL.readBytes(settings: HeaderSetter? = null): ByteArray {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(this).let {
            settings?.invoke(it) ?: it
        }.build()

    return client.newCall(request).execute().also { if (it.code() != 200) throw IOException("CODE ${it.code()}") }.body()?.use { it.bytes() } ?: throw IOException()
}


var clientHolder: OkHttpClient? = null
val client: OkHttpClient
    get() = clientHolder ?: clientBuilder.build().also {
        clientHolder = it
    }
```

How I do it in react-native ?

Comment: Fetch API is your friend! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @Stitt I don't mean fetch API, I mean handle data response after fetch

Comment: React Native uses JavaScript / Typescript. To read binary data using the Fetch API, you would use the [Response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob) method

Comment: @Phil I use "rn-fetch-blob" to call API, but data still encrypted: 
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', address).then(res => {
        console.log('blob', res.blob());
        console.log('base64', res.base64());)}

Answer (score 2):

For people arriving from search engines and looking to get an answer to the question as written in the title, the way to read bytes from a fetch response is to use [Response.arrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer) or [Response.blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob).

More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Some unsolicited tips for working with array buffers:

- To access individual bytes use [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) - i.e. `new Uint8Array(array)`
- To view bytes as a (a.k.a primitive hexdump) decode them as iso-8859-1 using [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) - i.e. `new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1")`
- To convert bytes to normal strings, also use TextDecoder.